# set password protection on nt3h211 2k through i2c (ntag i2c plus from nxp)

Tags: nfc

what is the procedure for setting password protection on nt3h211 2k using the i2c
interface?

i have to set password for the write operation only from the nfc perspective,
so do i need to to do the password authentication when writing data to nfc tag
from the i2c interface?

how to change the password or remove the password through i2c?

do i a have to send LSBytes first when writing password and pack through the i2c?

how to authenticate password through the i2c?

Comment: Those are way too many questions and too little indication of info you already have from your own research. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The datasheet for the tag https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NT3H2111_2211.pdf has all the answers.